# Display PowerPoint as slideshow on page

Tags: powerpoint

We have an organisation chart (PowerPoint 2013 file) that is updated regularly and available for download using a document library.

I was asked to display the content of the slide deck on the site page above the document library as a slide show.

Can someone advise me please of how I might do this Web Part / Html Code, without having to purchase a third party app?

Apologies I should have mentioned the version of SharePoint is 2013.

Answer (score 9):

In SharePoint 2010 (and later) it is possible to display powerpoint presentations / slides inside of a Page Viewer Web Part if you have the Office Web Apps installed on your SharePoint installation.

- Enable Office Web Apps in the Site Collection Features administration
  page
- Load your powerpoint into a document library somewhere on your site
- Inside of the Edit Control Block (a fancy SharePoint term for the
  dropdown menu that appears next to a list item when you select the
  expand arrow in its title -- see screenshot at bottom of this answer) select "View in Browser"
- On that page select "open in popup" at the top right of the page (this may also appear as 'Embed' in some systems)
- Copy the URL from that pop-up page, depending on your browser you may have to right click the page and select "properties" to see the full URL
- On the page you want to display the slide, edit the page and from the ribbon select Insert => WebPart => Media and Content => Page Viewer => Add
- open the tool pane as the webpart will prompt you (do save the page if prompted)
- in the "Link" box of the WebPart properties paste in the link to the pop-up page you viewed earlier with your powerpoint slide and select "Ok"

And your slide should appear on the page inside of that page viewer web part.

This technique has the advantage of updating the display automatically if you update the powerpoint file, but you might also just consider exporting the slide you're interested in as a picture and posting it into something like a content editor or the wiki edit area of the page you're working on.

Here is a walkthrough with some pictures of the page viewer technique on the nothingbutsharepoint site: http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/12/07/display-a-powerpoint-document-in-sharepoint-via-the-page-viewer-web-part-aspx/

And here is a screenshot of the Edit Control Block (or ECB):
[image: SharePoint 2010 Edit Control Block]

If you're having a hard time finding the "View in Browser" command, check out video number 6 on this page: https://support.office.com/en-au/article/SharePoint-document-libraries-I-An-introduction-a5a82359-bbde-46c8-9a0e-1a4628cc6603

And welcome to working with SharePoint!

Comment: The solution I have gone for; for the moment anyway, is saving the PowerPoint as an MP4 uploading it into the Library.  Then selecting Insert  |  Web Part  |  Insert Video |  Use Link  |   Paste Link of MP4 address in document library.

Comment: Huh -- well there are lots of choices! I also updated my answer to reflect that it works in 2010 and later (including 2013) not sure why I picked 2010 as the version I assumed you had!

Comment: Hi, 

I am trying to accomplish the same here but i don't seem to have the "open in pop-up" option on the top right corner. I only have the "?" and the "X".  I am using Office Web Apps 2013. 

Any ideas>?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to display your PowerPoint on a SharePoint page so I took the time to describe both of them to you so you can choose. (one way is user controlled while the other is automatic)

**Display PowerPoint on a Page**

First off you can display the PowerPoint on the page so users can view and interact with it on their own. (I'm not sure if built in PowerPoint slide timings work as I didn't test that out.) This can be done with the web part called **Page Viewer** + Office Web Apps to display the file in the browser.

1. Copy the Link to your PowerPoint file (menu > copy link)
   [image]
2. Create a wiki or web part page. (or use your sites home page) > Edit the page.
3. Insert the page viewer web part found in the Media and Content section
   [image]
4. Edit the web part (open the tool pane)
   [image]
5. Paste the Address into the URL field and make sure the **?web=1** parameter is on the end of the address after the ".ppt". (Also you may want to increase the height of the web part)
   [image]
6. Apply > OK > Save the page and your all set. Office Web Apps should display the document in that web part on the page. You can also replace the PowerPoint file in its stored location in the document library as long as the file name stays the same.
   [image]

**Display PowerPoint as a Slide Show**

To do this you will need to save your slide deck out as images and put them into a picture library. Then you can use the **Picture Library Slideshow Web Part** to display the images as a slide show.

1. From PowerPoint save the slides as images: (File > Save As > File Type:.jpg)
   [image]
2. Then export your slides as images
   [image]
3. Upload the images to a Picture Library on your site
4. Insert the Picture Library Slideshow Web Part to a page and point it to your library where the pictures are stored. > Apply > save page and your all set.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

MS hope you use office web app, but that is a lot of money, you also need office client permit, more complex your SharePoint site, benefit is you edit online;
Excel can show by Excel service, Visio can come with Visio show feature, access also has its service. But .docx word and .ppt should think about other solution like PDF.
if you client has some office client, like WPS can help IE show PPT in browser, but can't help Chrome, but Google is also powerful, you can find a extension named "Office editing", use this you can show on web browser, it looks like show online, the different just modify can't sync to server, that's the different online service and client application....